# Using CancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

Can somebody give an example, where I should use the next method with three arguments.

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;

Task.Factory.StartNew(MyTask, token, token);
```

Could you explain please, why we need a third argument?

Comment: What is MyTask? Is the first token actually the object parameter to MyTask? Try: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyTask(), token)`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no overload of `StartNew` that is `StartNew(Action, CancellationToken, CancellationToken)`.  Most likely, the method being called here is [`StartNew(Action<object>, object, CancellationToken)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780315(v=vs.110).aspx).

This overload starts the Action, passing in the provided object (second argument) as the argument for this Action.

I can only assume the reason for this is so that the Action can participate in the cooperative cancelling process that `CancellationToken` provides. In other words, it allows for not only the Task to cooperate in cancellation via the token, but you can use it in the Action in order to quit execution ASAP and possibly avoid a ThreadAbortedException.

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;

Task.Factory.StartNew(x =>
{
    var token = (CancellationToken)x;
    for(var item in ReallyBigCollection){
        Process(item, token);
        if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;
    }
}, token, token);
```

There isn't much reason to have a CancellationToken unless you're going to use it.

Comment: This is an original method from .NET:

public Task StartNew(Action<object> action, object state, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

Thank you for your example, but If you remove the third argument, your code still works.

Comment: I still don't understand why we use the second "token".

Comment: @Alexander The first token is passed into your asynchronous method so you can use it.  The second is passed to the Task factory so *it* knows when to abort.

Answer (score 2):

You seem confused by the method signature itself.

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427424/using-cancellationtokensource#comment48940634_30427548), you're actually calling `public Task StartNew(Action<object> action, object state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`.  But when calling it, you are using the following `Task.Factory.StartNew(MyTask, token, token)`.

So, yes, you are using `token` twice and you are trying to understand why you need to use `token` twice.

The answer is you are using the overload incorrectly (or not using the correct overload).

If you look at the [method documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780315(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see the following:

- **action** Type: `System.Action<Object>` - The action delegate to execute asynchronously.
- **state** Type: `System.Object` - An object containing data to be used by the action delegate.
- **cancellationToken** Type: `System.Threading.CancellationToken` - The CancellationToken that will be assigned to the new Task

So you are basically the one passing a `CancellationToken` as both the **cancellationToken** and the **state**.

You don't need to pass both.  As mentioned in the documentation, the 2nd argument ("state") is for data to be used by the action delegate, and you are passing the `CancellationToken`.  While it works, you are using an argument for something that it wasn't necessarily intended for (which can be confusing for someone else who inherits your code).

If you don't have data to pass to the `Action`, it is perfectly acceptable to pass a null.  And then you can use the overload with the appropriate `CancellationToken` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Cancellation tokens are provided to a asynchronous operation to help it determine the steps to execute while some 'cancel' event occurs.Obviously one can send a null.